# PyCharm DB tools unable to access MySQL DB with utf8mb4 encoding

Tags: pycharm, java-io

I am using the database tools in PyCharm (professional edition) with a MySQL 5.7 database that I just changed to use utf8mb4 encoding. However, now, the database tools won't access the database (i.e. I can't see what's in tables, etc.). I am getting the following message...

```
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: utf8mb4.
```

To be clear, this is not affecting my Python code's access to the database, it's only the DB tools that allow me to look into tables, etc. while I'm debugging. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

After working with Jetbrains support, we can to a solution... In your connection window, go to the advanced tab and make sure the character sets are set to utf8 **NOT** utf8mb4. Here is a picture of what is working for me...
[image]

Hope it helps!